# How to force FrameLog use FullName as TypeName in ObjectChange?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, logging

I am using FrameLog to save all changes made by EntityFramework. I have to create Type object based on TypeName property of ObjectChange class, but FrameLog stores only abbreviated name of an object type and method Type.GetType() generates an exception because it expects FullName.

So, how to force FrameLog save FullName as TypeName in ObjectChange class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite nested inside FrameLog, it isn't something you could easily change in user-land.

```
    public void Record(object entity, Func<string> deferredReference, string propertyName, Func<object> deferredValue)
    {
        ensureChangeSetExists();

        var typeName = ObjectContext.GetObjectType(entity.GetType()).Name;
        var deferredObjectChange = getOrCreateNewDeferredObjectChangeFor(set, entity, typeName, deferredReference);
        record(deferredObjectChange, propertyName, deferredValue);
    }
```

I have logged this issue on the FrameLog project site for you. (https://bitbucket.org/MartinEden/framelog/issues/94/iobjectchangetypename-should-include-the)

You could probably write a function which attempts to translate the type name back to a System.Type. Although, because you only have the class name, it's never going to be 100% reliable (i.e. duplicate class names in different namespaces, etc).

Here is a rough idea of what I mean, it isn't pretty or tested, but should point you in the right direction until the issue is addressed within FrameLog itself.

```
    FrameLogTypeToSystemType(myDbContext, myObjectChange);

    public Type FrameLogTypeToSystemType<TPrincipal>(DbContext db, IObjectChange<TPrincipal> objectChange)
    {
        var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
        var container = objectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetEntityContainer(objectContext.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace);
        foreach (var set in container.BaseEntitySets)
        {
            //if (set.ElementType.FullName.Contains(objectChange.TypeName)) might work better???
            if (set.ElementType.FullName.EndsWith(objectChange.TypeName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                return Type.GetType(set.ElementType.FullName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Because of the license is loyal enough, I decided my problem by downloading source code and customizing necessary parts.